# Why the Performance lag is reported in the following code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, instruments

I am using EasyTableView Library, Can you please tell me , When I am dynamically creating rows for my Tableview, why it is showing so much performance lag in the Instruments?

The Code in the above image is as follows:

```
CGRect buttonRect   = CGRectMake(10, 0, 473, 677);
    UIButton *button    = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = buttonRect;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, button.frame.size.height-100, button.frame.size.width,50)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [button addSubview:label];
    // Use a different color for the two different examples
    return button;
```

[image: Performance Lag]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're regenerating a cell view for every cell (i.e. never reusing the views).
Looking at the docs for EasyTableView, it looks like ETV does NOT incorporate a view caching mechanism, so it's generating new views for every row of the tableview.

And if your tableview has dozens or hundreds of rows, you are in deep trouble. I suggest getting rid of EasyTableView and using UITableViews that have cell view caching and reuse.

Alternatively, implement your own view caching and reuse. So in your case you'd have a pool of UIButtons, and every time you need to return a UIButton in `easyTableView:viewForRect:`, check if there's one that isn't currently visible on screen. If so, reuse it and change whatever you need (label text, etc...). Otherwise, create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell if you have any performance issues based on that screenshot, all there is that button takes 34% of time inside `viewForRect`, which is probably tiny. To get better picture open right sidebar in Instruments and see where time goes, or show your call trace with timing, not the code view.

Now, in general, creating cell views is not a bottleneck, but not reusing them in UITableView is.

Comment: Do I need to run the app and then catch the Call Trace with Timing?